# Hibernate 3.6.7 to 4.0.1 upgrade, nested transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I'm trying to upgrade from hibernate 3.6.7 to 4.0.1, and from JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.7.

After migrating configuration files ect ect... I can run my application fine.

First a bit of cfg.xml of my hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory< /property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

But I'm facing 1 a problem with nested sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction()
This used to be working in hibernate 3.6.7, though without a "hibernate.transaction.factory_class" property.

Anyone got a clue to what I'm doing wrong?

Stack trace is like this:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:152)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1263)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:350)
at $Proxy4.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation it looks like Hibernate never supported nested transactions, and that this was enforced in Hibernate 4, since that class AbstractTransactionImpl didn't exist before.

I don't know what you are trying to solve with nested transactions, but maybe there is an alternate way to do it, using only a single one.